# wrong result printed to the console

Tags: python, methods, super, python-class

I have the following code, which should print 3500.0 to the console:

```
class Employee:
    
    """ Creates an instance of Employee """
    
    def __init__(self, name, annual_salary):
        self.name = name
        self.annual_salary = annual_salary
        
    def calculate_monthly_salary(self):
        return annual_salary / 0.12
        

class CustomerServiceEmployee(Employee):
    
    """ Creates an instance of CustomerServiceEmployee """
    
    def __init__(self, name, annual_salary, department):
        super().__init__(name, annual_salary)
        self.department = department

cs_manager = CustomerServiceEmployee("Kelly Johnson", 42000, "Customer Service")
kellys_monthly_salary = Employee.calculate_monthly_salary
print(kellys_monthly_salary)
```

but instead it prints:

```
<function Employee.calculate_monthly_salary at 0x7fdfb1db31f0>
```

I am led to believe my issue is in the method calculate_monthly_salary but I can't for the life of me sort it out. Could anybody shed some light please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have created an object for `CustomerServiceEmployee` already and stored that in `cs_manager`. So why not use it?

```
kellys_monthly_salary = cs_manager.calculate_monthly_salary()
```

also `line 10` should have `self`.

```
self.annual_salary
```

full code

```
class Employee:
    
    """ Creates an instance of Employee """
    
    def __init__(self, name, annual_salary):
        self.name = name
        self.annual_salary = annual_salary
        
    def calculate_monthly_salary(self):
        return self.annual_salary / 0.12
        

class CustomerServiceEmployee(Employee):
    
    """ Creates an instance of CustomerServiceEmployee """
    
    def __init__(self, name, annual_salary, department):
        super().__init__(name, annual_salary)
        self.department = department

cs_manager = CustomerServiceEmployee("Kelly Johnson", 42000, "Customer Service")
kellys_monthly_salary = cs_manager.calculate_monthly_salary()
print(kellys_monthly_salary)
```

Comment: Ah! Missed self on line 10 (I fixed that whilst waiting for a good Samaritan like you!) but I didn't think of using the object for CustomerServiceEmployee - you are magic! thank you very much it worked perfectly, cheers!